# Match multiple patterns with a Regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have 3 groups : time, date and pin. And i can have this line to match this lines :

> 26/06/2012 33:06:12a_user_logged_in,3412234,2,3,512,3
>   33:06:12a_user_logged_in,3412234,2,3,512,3,26/06/2012
>   26/06/2012 a_user_logged_in_at,33:06:12,3412234,2,3,512,3

I want to match `26/06/2012` as the `date` group, `33:06:12` as the `time` and `3412234` as the `pin` group.

I've succeeded in doing so but only the line must be in a certain pattern like the first one

```
(?<date>[\d]+/[\d]+/[\d]+) (?<time>[\d]+:[\d]+:[\d]+)([ |,][a-zA-z]*)+,(?<pin>[\d]{4,10}).+
```

But when i apply this pattern to the other two lines forms, it didn't match.

My question is, how to match time, date and pin groups no matter what was the line form ?

Comment: The patterns don't seem to cross-match, so why not match sequentially? Also, please specify the language/tool you use in `[regex]` questions.

Comment: I've updated the question, also updated the given pattern. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to validate the pattern at the same time, you can use [lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) starting from the beginning of the string. Since they don't actually consume anything, the engine jumps back to the start after completing one lookahead. Hence, the order of the three matches does not matter:

```
^(?=.*(?<date>\d+/\d+/\d+))(?=.*(?<time>\d+:\d+:\d+))(?=.*,(?<pin>\d{4,10}))
```

Note the `,` in front of the `pin` group. Otherwise you risk that the year is found as the pin (since it is also 4 digits).

But then again, for the sake of readability of your code you might want to just split that into three patterns (this also avoids capturing so it might not even be that much slower):

```
Pattern for date: \d+/\d+/\d+
Pattern for time: \d+:\d+:\d+
Pattern for pin:  (?<=,)\d{4,10}
```

These will simply give you your desired values as the entire match.

Comment: The provided link of lookaheads is quite a read. Can you provide me with a simpler link about it ? Or just explain to me how lookahead works ? Thanks.

Comment: @RafaelAdel basically, when entering a lookahead the engine remembers it's current position. then it just continues trying to find a match as usual (i.e. it will just try to match `^.*(?<date>\d+/\d+/\d+)`). Once, it's done that, it will jump back to where it entered the lookahead (in this case the beginning of the string). That's all there is to it (since we only use positive lookaheads here).

Answer (score 11):

Just add `|` between your expressions:

```
(?<date>[\d]+/[\d]+/[\d]+)|(?<time>[\d]+:[\d]+:[\d]+)|(?<pin>(?<=[^/])[\d]{4,10})
```

Comment: Note that this will create three matches with one non-empty group each.

Comment: @MartinEnder or user1006989, if you are still here can you tell me how can I serparate them later if I am using MatchCollection ?